# readFile, escope and class Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using readFile json to return array messages, object return empty array, why?

My code:

```
var fs = require("fs"); // filesystem

class Message {

   constructor() {
      this._message_list = [];
   }

   set message_list(val) {

      this._message_list = val;
   }

   get message_list() {
     return this._message_list;
   }

   getMessages() {

      fs.readFile("./models/messages-list.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
       if(err){
         return err;
       }
        // append array messages
        this._message_list = Object.keys(JSON.parse(data));
        console.log(this._message_list); // return ["message 1", "message 2"]
});

    return this._message_list; // return array messages
 }

}

module.exports = {
  Message
};


var Message = require("./models/message");

let mensagem = null;
mensagem = new Message.Message();
console.log( mensagem.getMessages()); //return []
```

How return my array messages? Way my this._message_list return empty array?

Comment: `readFile` is asynchronous. Have a [read at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Because `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, it won't return before you do:

```
// return array messages
return this._message_list;
```

If you use `fs.readFileSync`, this should work..

```
getMessages() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync("./models/messages-list.json", "utf8");

    this._message_list = Object.keys(JSON.parse(data));

    // log ["message 1", "message 2"]
    console.log(this._message_list);

    // return array messages
    return this._message_list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but Dont Work with readFileSync

Comment: Hi csassis, I updated the answer with a change to getMessages() that illustrates the use of readFileSync, I hope this helps you!